# Twitter search api 1.1 and PHP CURL: Could not authenticate you

Tags: php, rest, curl, twitter

I am using James Mallisons Twitter-API from Github:
http://github.com/j7mbo/twitter-api-php

After passing the authentication credentials I try to get a list of tweets around defined geo coordinates:

```
$fields = "?q=test&geocode=".urlencode("$lat,$lon,$radius")."&count=100";
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$method = 'GET';
$result = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $method)
    ->setGetfield($fields)
    ->performRequest();
```

This generates the following CURL Opts to be set inside the api class:
(masked auth credentials with XXX)

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
CURLOPT_HEADER => 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXX", oauth_nonce="XXX", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_token="XXX", oauth_timestamp="XXX", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="XXX"',
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=test&geocode=48.39677%2C9.98042%2C35km&count=100",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
```

A request made with this options results in the following error:

```
["message"]=>
  string(26) "Could not authenticate you"
["code"]=>
  int(32)
```

Do you have an idea about this error?
Getting my friendlist from /friends/ids.json works great.
So the authentication is correct.
Seems to be an error with the query parameters.

Comment: Your answer that you marked as 'correct' is *incorrect for future viewers*. If anyone used the library previously and searches for this issue, the current answer isn't good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the author made a critical fix to encoding of commas just a few days ago.
https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/commit/5c2b97e402d04114ca3be6a793eebcd8521d76a5

My guess is that's why your geocode call fails and your friend/ids is fine.
Best update the library.

Try [mine](https://github.com/timwhitlock/php-twitter-api) if you're still stuck

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** I've +1'd Tim's answer, *make sure you have the latest version* ;)

### Your Issue - don't urlencode!

Okay, your exact issue is that you *don't* need to `urlencode()` your location stuff. It should be a plain old GET request.

According to the [docs for geocode](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets):

> Example Values: 37.781157,-122.398720,1mi

Putting this into the getfield works:

```
$getfield = '?q=test&geocode=37.781157,-122.398720,1mi&count=100';
```

So make sure it's in the format according to the docs and you're good to go. I'll add this example to the [wiki](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/wiki/Twitter-API-PHP-Wiki) as well.